# Support for count(DISTINCT) or any other collect-like operation in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I use Memegraph in Dockerized environment. Memgraph version is 2.4.1. I have a need for  `count(DISTINCT)` or some other collect-like operation. But I [can't find it in the docs](https://memgraph-archive-docs.netlify.app/memgraph/2.4.1/).

Is this supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked the latest available Memgraph (version 2.10). It supports `RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n.prop)`. Documentation can be found at https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/return#10-returning-unique-results.